# La variable regresa antes que pueda convertir la información de ima imagen

Tags: javascript, angular

Estoy trabajando un servicio de Angular el cual me ayuda a controlar errores y/o mostrar una imagen en base64. Todo va bien, pero me confundo en los `return`. Como puedo salir de la función general cuando encuentro un error, y regresar un objeto que tiene dos índices, el error y la base64

Este es mi archivo

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ToolsService {

  constructor() {}

  viewImg(file: Blob, maxSize: number, maxHeight ?: number, maxWidth ?: number): any {

    const ret = {
      error: null,
      base: null
    };
    const fileType = /image.*/;
    if (!file.type.match(fileType)) {
      ret.error = 'El archivo no es una imagen valida';
      return ret;
    }

    if (Math.ceil(file.size / 1024) > maxSize) {
      ret.error = `El archivo pesa ${ Math.ceil( file.size / 1024 ) }Kb, sólo ${ ( maxSize ) }Kb permitidos`;
      return ret;
    }

    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = () => {
      const res: any = reader.result;
      const img      = new Image();
      ret.base       = res;
      img.src        = res;
      console.log( 'CARGANDO IMG' );

      img.onload = () => {
        console.log( 'CONVIRTIENDO IMG' );
        if (img.width > maxWidth || img.height > maxHeight) {
          ret.error = `Archivo sobredimensionado, ${ img.width } x ${ img.height }px. Permitido ${ maxWidth } x ${ maxHeight }px`;
          return ret;
        }
        ret.base = res;
      };
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    return ret;
  }
}
```

Así lo invoco

```
preview( ev: any ) {
    if( ev.target.files[0] ) {
      const base64 = this._tools.viewImg( ev.target.files[0], 250, 100, 100 );
      console.log( base64 );
    }
  }
```

Y el resultado en consola tiene este orden

> new.component.ts:22 {error: null, base: null}
>
> tools.service.ts:36 CARGANDO IMG
>
> tools.service.ts:39 CONVIRTIENDO IMG

Es decir, está regresando el resultado y luego lo está procesando.
He pensado en utilizar una promesa, pero sinceramente no tengo mucha experiencia haciendolas.

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Answer (score 1):

El evento *onload* es asíncrono y se ejecuta fuera del scope de tu función. Tendrías que convertir tu función a tipo **Promise** para poder controlar el evento:

```js
viewImg(file: Blob, maxSize: number, maxHeight ?: number, maxWidth ?: number): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
    // Aquí realizas la implementación de tu función
  })
}
```

Posteriormente dentro del evento *onload* de tu imagen puedes ejecutar la función *resolve* de tu Promise, pasándole como parámetro el result de tu FileReader:

```js
img.onload = () => {
  // Implementación del evento onload
  resolve(res);
};
```

La invocación quedaría de esta mánera:

```js
this._tools.viewImg( ev.target.files[0], 250, 100, 100 ).then(data => {
  const base64 = data;
  console.log( base64 );
})
```